# Как получить все значения в скобках из строки на javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть к примеру такая строка:

```
var a = "myfunc('list', '5654124523524', 145, '2', '123513124123')";
```

Как получить значения `list`, `5654124523524`, `145`, `2`, `123513124123` из переменной `a`?

Comment: Если просто извлечь значения в кавычках, это будет неправильно?

Comment: Как именно можно извлечь?

Answer (score 1):

Можно искать блоки, окруженные запятыми и скобками

```
(?<=, |\().+?(?=,|\))
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fqB8Na/2)

в js, к сожалению Lookbehind не работает. поэтому regex немного поменялся

```js
var str = "myfunc('list', '5654124523524', 145, '2', '123513124123')";
var re = /(?:\(|, )(.+?)(?=,|\))/g;
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null)
  res.push(m[1]);

for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
  console.log(res[i]);
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, как в javascript всё это реализовать

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А можно и через `eval()` :D

```js
var a = "myfunc('list', '5654124523524', 145, '2', '123513124123')";
    
eval(a);
    
function myfunc(a, b, c, d, e) {
    console.log(a, b, c, d, e);
}
```

Comment: Или `function myfunc() {
    console.log(arguments);
}`

Comment: К сожалению eval выводит код, а так всё отлично было бы